# UISwitch in headerview of UITableView is changing state but not calling event handle method

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uiswitch

I am working on a project which has `UITableView` with `UISwitch` on headerview. Following is my code for header view. I have tried different questions regarding button click event on headerview but none of the solutions seems to work.

If it helps, I am setting `UITableView` header height.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100;
}
```

Here is the code for my header.

```
class NotificationSettingsTableHeaderView : UIView, ViewProtocol {

    //other controls
    var mainSwitch : UISwitch!
    var contentView : UIView!

    weak var temp: SettingCellDelegate?

    func handle(sender: UISwitch) {

     // ----------- THIS METHOD IS NOT GETTING CALLED ------------
        if(sender.isOn){
            print("IS ON")
        }
        else{
            print("IS OFF")
        }

    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubviews()
        makeConstraints()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func addSubviews() {

        contentView = UIView()

    // Other control initialization
        mainSwitch = UISwitch()
        mainSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NotificationSettingsTableHeaderView.handle(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        contentView.addSubview(mainSwitch)

    }

    func makeConstraints() {

        let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds

        contentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screen.width, height: 80)
        mainSwitch.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.centerY.equalTo(contentView)
            make.right.equalTo(contentView).offset(-10)
        }
        // other code

    }    
}
```

**Edited**

I am adding contentview to header using following code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView {

    let cell = NotificationSettingsTableHeaderView()
    let cat = preferenceSection.allSections[section]
    cell.label.text = cat.getTitle()
    cell.descLabel.text = cat.getSubtitle()
    return cell.contentView
}
```

Here is how my header view look. I am even able to turn on/off switch
   [image]

Comment: Are you *seeing* the `UISwitch` in the header view? Are you seeing *anything* in the header view? I don't see where you are adding `contentView` to the header view...

Comment: Yes I am able to see entire header view. I am even able to click on `UISwitch` and turn it on/off. @DonMag

Comment: @DonMag Please review my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have your UISwitch in your `UIView` hierarchy, as @DonMag says, seems that you have forgot add your contentView to view hierarchy, Your handle method is an instance method, don't a class method, so

**Change this line in your `addSubviews` method**

```
mainSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NotificationSettingsTableHeaderView.handle(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

**by this one**

```
mainSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handle(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

## Updated 1

You need return your `NotificationSettingsTableHeaderView` object and you are returning the contentView instead

change this line in your `viewForHeaderInSection` method of your `UITableViewDelegate`

```
return cell.contentView
```

by this  one

```
return cell
```

## Updated 2

```
func addSubviews() {

        contentView = UIView()

    // Other control initialization
        mainSwitch = UISwitch()
        mainSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NotificationSettingsTableHeaderView.handle(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        self.addSubview(mainSwitch)
    }

func makeConstraints() {

    mainSwitch.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.centerY.equalTo(self)
        make.right.equalTo(self).offset(-10)
    }
    // other code

}
```

Comment: I tried that too. It is still not working. @Reinier Melian

Comment: @Pooja check my answer again

Comment: @Pooja you need return cell in your viewForHeader in section method, you are returning the content view that is why is not working at all

Comment: If I return cell then I am not able to see my entire header. @Reinier Melian

Comment: thats is because you are missing add the contentView as was said by @DonMag

Comment: @Pooja - inside `NotificationSettingsTableHeaderView`, you need to add `contentView` as a subview, and then use the entire view.

Comment: @Pooja or even you can avoid the contentView part and add your control directly on your NotificationSettingsTableHeaderView i will update my answer again

Comment: Thank you @DonMag